# Is it possible to get the current position of an ipywidget?

Tags: python, vuetify.js, ipywidgets

I'm using the `ipyvuetfy` lib that create nice dashboarding element based ont he `vuetify.js` lib and `ipyvwidgets`.

I need to place a dialog in a specific position (on top of another element) like this menu placed on top of a select folder btn.

[image]

How can I access the the current position of a widget relative to the window ?

Comment: Could you include a screen shot as an example? Do you mean 'above' rather than 'on top of' another element?

Comment: Since it is to be on top of a button, why not using v.Menu as in ipyvuetify [example](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify/blob/322048b2095552e290e7f42f0aaadf25f87dc708/examples/Examples.ipynb#L179)?

Comment: in the example I use a v.Menu, but as specified in the question I need to place a v.Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with Javascript code, by identifying the widget with a custom class and using the [jQuery offset()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp) method, and then setting the [DOM Style top](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_top.asp) and left properties of the child (here a Card) of the ipyvuetify Dialog, with the style `position` set as `fixed`. I haven't found how to execute the JS code via the Dialog activator slot, so the Dialog widget is triggered via the [`click.stop`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/#without-activator) event:

```py
import ipyvuetify as v
import ipywidgets as w

from IPython.display import Javascript

out = w.Output(layout={'display': 'none'})

js = '''
var x = $(".myparentwidget").offset();
var d = document.getElementsByClassName("mydialog")[0]; 
d.style.top = x.top+"px"; 
d.style.left= x.left+"px";'''

def on_click(widget, event, data):
    dialog.v_model=True
    with out:
        display(Javascript(js, lib="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"))

btn = v.Btn(
    children=["Open dialog"],
    class_='myparentwidget'
)
btn.on_event("click.stop", on_click)

dialog = v.Dialog(
    v_model=False,
    children=[
        v.Card(
            class_='mydialog',
            style_="position: fixed; width: 300px",
            children=[
                v.CardTitle(children=["Dialog window"]),
                v.CardText(children=['Dialog text']),
            ]
        )
    ],
)

v.Layout(children=[btn,dialog,out])
```